# Getting Product author id in products permalinks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I am using woo commerce and WC Vendor plugin to make a vendor shop. Now I want the product author ID as well in the permalink of the woo commerce product does anyone have any idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution by writing a simple function in functions.php file the function that worked for me is

```
add_filter('post_type_link', 'add_author_id', 10, 4);

function add_author_id($post_link, $post, $leavename, $sample) {
if ('product' != get_post_type($post))
    return $post_link;
$authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$author = $authordata->id;
$post_link = str_replace('%author%', $author, $post_link);
return $post_link;
 }
```